# Vue infinite UI update loop with function as param

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new in **Vue.js** and tried to convert some legacy code for pagination. I've created a pager component which accepts a function as one of its params. But it's causing an infinite UI render loop.

Could you help me to resolve or suggest some solution for such problem?

Here is my pager component js:

```
const PagerComponent = {
name: "pagerComponent",
template: "#pagerComponent",
props: {
    pageSize: Number,
    pageIndex: Number,
    totalPages: Number,
    totalRecords: Number,
    pageSlide: Number,
    hasNextPage: Boolean,
    hasPrevPage: Boolean,
    pages: Array,
    loadFunc: Function
},
data() {
    return {
        pager: {
            pageSize: 0,
            pageIndex: 0,
            totalPages: 0,
            totalCount: 0,
            pageSlide: 1,
            hasNextPage: false,
            hasPrevPage: false,
            pages: [],
            loadFunc: function () { }
        }
    }
},
methods: {
    load(index) {
        this.pager.pageIndex = index;
        if (this.pager.loadFunc != null) {
            this.pager.loadFunc();
        }
    },
    isActivePage(page) {
        return this.pager.pageIndex + 1 == page;
    },
    update(newPager) {
        this.pager.pageSize = newPager.pageSize;
        this.pager.pageIndex = newPager.pageIndex;
        this.pager.totalPages = newPager.totalPages;
        this.pager.totalCount = newPager.totalCount;
        this.pager.hasNextPage = newPager.hasNextPage;
        this.pager.hasPrevPage = newPager.hasPrevPage;
        this.generatePages();
    },
    generatePages() {
        this.pager.pages = [];
        var pageNum = this.pager.pageIndex + 1;
        var pageFrom = Math.max(1, pageNum - this.pager.pageSlide);
        var pageTo = Math.min(this.pager.totalPages, pageNum + this.pager.pageSlide);
        pageFrom = Math.max(1, Math.min(pageTo - this.pager.pageSlide, pageFrom));
        pageTo = Math.min(this.pager.totalPages, Math.max(pageFrom + this.pager.pageSlide, pageNum == 1 ? pageTo + this.pager.pageSlide : pageTo));

        for (var i = pageFrom; i <= pageTo; i++) {
            this.pager.pages.push(i);
        }
    }
},
computed: {
    hasPages() {
        if (this.pager.pages == null)
            return false;
        return this.pager.pages.length > 0;
    },
    doNotHavePrevPage() {
        return !this.pager.hasPrevPage;
    },
    doNotHaveNextPage() {
        return !this.pager.hasNextPage;
    }
},
beforeMount() {
    this.pager.pageSize = this.pageSize;
    this.pager.pageIndex = this.pageIndex;
    this.pager.totalPages = this.totalPages;
    this.pager.totalCount = this.totalRecords;
    this.pager.hasNextPage = this.hasNextPage;
    this.pager.hasPrevPage = this.hasPrevPage;
    this.pager.loadFunc = this.loadFunc;
    this.pager.pages = this.pages || [];
    this.generatePages();
},
mounted() {
}
```

}

Here is how it's used in html:

```
<pager-Component v-bind="Pager" v-bind:load-Func="GetItems" ref="pager"></pager-Component>
```

And GetItems funciton:

```
function () {
        var self = this;
        const data = {
            Pager: self.Pager,
            Filter: []
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: self.GetItemsUrl,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            busy: self.Loading,
            data: data
        }).done(function (result) {
            if (result.isSuccess) {
                self.$refs.pager.update(result.data.pager);
                self.Items.splice(0);
                result.data.items.map(function (value, key) {
                    self.Items.push(value);
                });
            }
            else {
                alert(result.data.errors[0]);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You should take a look at [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/). I think this would make your life a lot easier.

Comment: @Fabalance thanks for your response, but it looks like this lib is a easy-way to resolve component name handling
And my problem is in infinite loop, when i add items into array, it's rendered and each item added to list causes method call in component

Comment: try putting a console.log into `beforeMount()`  and see if that one is constantly logged.

If thats the case you are constantly re-mounting the component causing it constantly call `generatePages()` and then `.update()`

Comment: @flx beforeMount() was called just once for Pager component

Comment: @flx I've found 2 places which causes infinite loops:
1. v-bind:load-Func="GetItems" - this one makes it realy infinite calling load func
2. this.pager.pageIndex = index; - this one makes second infinite loop inside load func

Comment: is the loadFunc needed inside data block? I think the one in props alone is enough. Try removing that and check once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after tones of tests, the solution was found and it's pretty easy.

I just needed to use **v-on:click** instead of **:click**. I just don't know why lot of tutorials suggest to use :click if it doesn't work

So for example use

```
<div v-on:click="load(pageIndex)">My button</div>
```

instead of

```
<div :click="load(pageIndex)">My button</div>
```